# Limit of Twilio Device Using same client name

Tags: twilio

In [this documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens#allow-incoming-connections), it is said that the number of simultaneous Twilio devices with same client name is limited. Since on each browser tab, a new Twilio Device is created, how many tabs can be opened for the same client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I've learned that you can open up to 10 tabs before new Twilio Devices will take over from old ones.

I'd watch out when encouraging users to do this as results can be a little weird. If you have 10 clients and they receive a call, they will all try to ring in the browser. It might be better to try to build the interface such that users are better served within one tab with one live client.